# Браузер воспроизводит mp3 файлы с другого сервера вместо скачивание

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .htaccess

Здравствуйте!
Имеется скажем 2 сервера, на 1-ом сервере стоит сам сайт, а на втором хранится музыка, но на втором сервере я не могу редактировать файл .htaccess.
Обясню зачем нужно редактировать этот файл: со 2-го сервера выдаются файлы с mime-type mpeg/mp3. Из за этого когда я ставлю прямые ссылки на сайт, музыка воспроизводится браузером вместо скачивание.
Главный вопрос, как сделать так чтобы музыка скачивалась. 
Пишите любой метод, варинт, если не трудно с примерами.

Comment: Можно попробовать сначала скачать файл на клиенте с помощью javascript, а затем предложить сохранить его.

Answer (score 1):

```
function download($URL, $filename) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\"");
    $fileHeader = fopen($URL, 'r', false);
    fpassthru($fileHeader);
    fclose($fileHeader);
}

download('https://cs9-5v4.vk.me/p12/4986cda949df08.mp3', 'Вариант1.mp3');
```

Если не сработает. Проверьте настройку PHP `allow_url_fopen`

Вариант№2. Менее приемлемый

```
function download($URL, $filename){
    $data =  base64_encode(file_get_contents($URL, FILE_BINARY));
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\"");
    $stream = fopen('data:text/plain;base64,' .$data, 'r');
    fpassthru($stream);
    fclose($stream);
}

download('https://psv4.vk.me/c611317/u55640938/audios/f186a32dd8d4.mp3','Вариант2.mp3');
```